# Generating random correlation matrix with given average correlation

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I would like to generate a random correlation **matrix in R** of 1000*1000 where the average correlation (excluding diagonal) is 0.3.

I looked at `genPositiveDefMat` from library clusterGeneration but I couldn't figure out how to specify a given correlation.

Comment: If you know that the pairwise correlations have got mean 0.3, why not just generating number between 0 and 1 with mean 0.3 and filling the matrix in this way?

Comment: correlation is between -1 and 1, however if you're directly filling up the correlation matrix, random may not work. You have to check for positive definiteness.

Comment: Yes that is a good point

Comment: Must the mean correlation be exactly 0.3? Somewhat hacky, you could convert a 1000x1000 covariance matrix with all off-diagonal elements equal to 0.3 to a covariance matrix, then use this covariance matrix to generate large random matrices with `mvrnorm` from the MASS package. Then calculate `cor()` on this large matrix, which would give you a correlation matrix with average correlations of approximately 0.3.

Comment: This is a great idea. If you posted it as an answer I could accept it.

Answer (score 1):

A boring example of such a matrix would be

```
C = (1-m)*I + m*U*U'
```

where I is the identity matrix, U a vector of all ones and m = 0.3. C is positive definite and the average (indeed every) off-diagonal element is m.

So we could try generating a matrix of the form

```
C = D + alpha*U*U'
```

where D is diagonal and positive definite, alpha a positive scaler and U a 'random' vector. Such a matrix will be positive definite. For this to have the correct average of the off diagonal elements a little algebra shows

```
alpha = dim*(dim-1)*m / (S*S-T)
```

where

```
S = Sum{ i | U[i] }
T = Sum{ i | U[i]*U[i]}
```

As long as all the elements of U are positive, we will have

```
S*S>T
```

and so alpha will be positive.

For the diagonal elements of C to be 1.0, we require

```
D[i] = 1 - alpha*U[i]*U[i] (i=1..dim)
```

and all of these must be non negative.

Alas I have been unable to find theoretically how the elements of U should be chosen to guarantee this. However experimentally, if the elements of U are uniform random numbers between 1.0 and 5.0, I've not seen a case where any of the D[i] are negative.

The upper limit for the elements of U, 5.0 above, controls how different the various correlations are. With 5.0 they vary between around 0.03 and 0.8, whild with an upper limit of 2.0 they vary between around 0.13 and 0.53.
Choosing the upper limit too high will increase the likelihood of the method failing (D not positive).