# Generate random matrix given a correlation value to an input matrix

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

Given an input matrix and a correlation Rho, I want to generate a random matrix that is correlated to the input matrix with a correlation value of Rho.

I can create random matrices through rnorm, but I'm not sure how to force this new matrix to be correlated to the original input matrix.

I looked through some other posts such as this but couldn't find what I was looking for. For example, this post [Generating random correlation matrix with given average correlation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357159/generating-random-correlation-matrix-with-given-average-correlation) looks to calculate a random matrix, but correlated to itself, not an input matrix.

Comment: You need to give an example of how you are calculating the correlation between two matrices.

Comment: see https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-April/128925.html and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83172/generate-two-variables-with-precise-pre-specified-correlation